# Stop method/object immediately?

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I'm working on an iOS app that uses data from a MySQL server on the web. I created a class called "DataController" that completely manages the synchronization-proccess and uses NSURLConnection with delegate to retrieve information, parse it and store it in CoreData models. It uses several methods in this process, like this:

> [self.dataControllerObject syncStudents]
>
> *syncStudents* is called
>   --> gets download-list from server
>   --> stores IDs for all elements that have to be downloaded in NSArray-property
>   --> calls *syncNextStudent*
>
> *syncNextStudent* is called
>   --> gets first element from NSArray-property
>   --> builds up NSURLConnection to retrieve data
>
> *connectionDidFinishLoading* is called
>   --> data is stored in CoreData
>   --> ID is removed from NSArray-property
>   --> calls *syncNextStudent*
>
> *syncNextStudent* eventually has no array elements left and finishes the process.

I hope I made clear the functionality. Now here's my problem:

**How do I abort the whole process, e.g. when the user does not want to sync now and hits some button?**

I tried to create the DataController object and call the syncStudents method an another thread using [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startSyncing) withObject:nil], but now my NSURLConnection does not trigger any delegate methods.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using `NSOperation`s and an `NSOperationQueue` instead of `performSelectorInBackground:`. This allows you to have more control over a batch of tasks that need to be performed in the background as well as cancel all operations at once . Here's what I suggest.

Declare an `NSOperationQueue` as a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
```

Then instantiate it in your implementation file:

```
_operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue] alloc] init];
```

Create an `NSOperation` derived class that will do the processing.

```
@interface StudentOperation : NSOperation

// Declare a property for your student ID
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *studentID;

@end
```

Then iterate through whatever collection you have to create your operations.

```
for (NSSNumber *studentID in studentIDs) { // Your array of ids
    StudentOperation *operation = [[StudentOperation alloc] init];

    // Add any parameters your operation needs like student ID
    [operation setStudentID:studentID];

    // Add it to the queue
    [_operationQueue addOperation:operation]; 
}
```

When you want to cancel, just tell the operation queue:

```
[_operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Keep in mind that this will immediately cancel any operations that are queued that are *not currently being processed*. If you want to stop any operations currently running, you have to add code to your `NSOperation` derived class (`StudentOperation` above) that checks for this. So, say your `NSOperation` code is running its main() function. You need to periodically check and see if the `cancelled` flag has been set.

```
@implementation StudentOperation

- (void)main
{
    // Kick off your async NSURLConnection download here.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL...

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    // ...
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the data
    [receivedData appendData:data];

    // Check and see if we need to cancel
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        // Close the connection. Do any other cleanup

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, learned something new already! One Question: How should I access CoreData in this structure? Should every _StudentOperation_ object have its own NSManagedObjectModel, NSPersistantStoreCoordinator etc? If no (I think so), what is the best was to access them if only the _DataController_ has them?

Comment: You only want one persistent store coordinator and one managed object model, however, you'll want to process the returned data in a background thread which means you need to create an NSManagedObjectContext in the background thread that you'll use to perform the import. And once you've finished importing, you have to save that context and notify your main context of the update. Also, take a look at mogenerator (http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) which automatically generates managed objects based on your CoreData model. I suggest you ask a separate specific question to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a BOOL **Property** *doSync* which is public.

Each time when your calling

*syncStudents is called* or *syncNextStudent is called* or *connectionDidFinishLoading*

check for

```
if(doSync){
    // *syncStudents is called* OR
    // *syncNextStudent is called* OR
    // *connectionDidFinishLoading* 
}
```

No you can change doSync to **FALSE** to stop your process.

```
 self.dataControllerObject.doSync = FALSE;
```

Comment: I tried that, but the property value is not changed within the running process.